# async Future StreamSubscription Error

Tags: dart

Could someone please explain what's wrong with the following code. I'm making two calls to the function fInputData. The first works ok, the second results in an error :
"unhandled exception"
"Bad state: Stream already has subscriber"

I need to write a test console program that inputs multiple parameters.

```java
import "dart:async" as async;
import "dart:io"; 

void main() {
  fInputData ("Enter Nr of Iterations : ")
  .then((String sResult){
    int iIters;
    try {
      iIters = int.parse(sResult);
      if (iIters < 0) throw new Exception("Invalid");
    } catch (oError) {
      print ("Invalid entry");
      exit(1);
    }

    print ("In Main : Iterations selected = ${iIters}");

    fInputData("Continue Processing? (Y/N) : ")   // this call bombs
    .then((String sInput){
      if (sInput != "y" && sInput != "Y")
        exit(1);

      fProcessData(iIters);

      print ("Main Completed");
    });
  });
}

async.Future<String> fInputData(String sPrompt) {
  async.Completer<String> oCompleter = new async.Completer(); 

  stdout.write(sPrompt);
  async.Stream<String> oStream = stdin.transform(new StringDecoder());
  async.StreamSubscription oSub;
  oSub = oStream.listen((String sInput) {
    oCompleter.complete(sInput);
    oSub.cancel();
  });
  return oCompleter.future;
}

void fProcessData(int iIters) {
  print ("In fProcessData");
  print ("iIters = ${iIters}");

  for (int iPos = 1; iPos <= iIters; iPos++ ) {
    if (iPos%100 == 0) print ("Processed = ${iPos}");
  }
  print ("In fProcessData - completed ${iIters}");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some [background reading](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/feet-wet-streams/):

> Streams comes in two flavours: single or multiple (also known as
>   broadcast) subscriber. By default, our stream is a single-subscriber
>   stream. This means that **if you try to listen to the stream more than
>   once, you will get an exception**, and using any of the callback
>   functions or future properties counts as listening.
>
> You can convert the single-subscriber stream into a broadcast stream
>   by using the [asBroadcastStream](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Stream.html#asBroadcastStream)() method.

So you've got two options - either re-use a single subscription object. i.e. call listen once, and keep the subscription object alive.

Or use a broadcast stream - note there are a number of differences between broadcast streams and single-subscriber streams, you'll need to read about those and make sure they suit your use-case.

Here's an example of reusing a subscriber to ask multiple questions:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

main() {
    var console = new Console();
    var loop;
    loop = () => ask(console).then((_) => loop());
    loop();
}

Future ask(Console console) {
    print('1 + 1 = ...');
    return console.readLine().then((line) {
        print(line.trim() == '2' ? 'Yup!' : 'Nope :(');
    });
}

class Console {
    StreamSubscription<String> _subs;

    Console() {
        var input = stdin
            .transform(new StringDecoder())
            .transform(new LineTransformer());

        _subs = input.listen(null);
    }

    Future<String> readLine() {
        var completer = new Completer<String>();
        _subs.onData(completer.complete);
        return completer.future;
    }
}
```